# Exoplayer - ConcatenatingMediaSource between main URL

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to concatenate Three video urls and play with Exoplayer **ConcatenatingMediaSource**.

What I am tried:

```
MediaSource mainSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(firstVideoUri, ...);
MediaSource secondSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(secondVideoUri, ...);
MediaSource thirdSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(thirdVideoUri, ...);
// Plays the first video, then second & third video.
ConcatenatingMediaSource concatenatedSource =
    new ConcatenatingMediaSource(mainSource, secondSource, thirdSource);
```

This one works for sequence video playing.

**My problem**

My mainSource is movie (~2 hours)

My secondSource & thirdSource are video Ads (2 mins)

I need to play first video advertisement after 30 mins movie played. 
And need to play second video advertisement after 60 mins movie played.

I need play 3 videos in following sequence

main movie (first 30 min) --> 2 min first ads --> main movie (31-60 mins)  --> 2 min second ads --> main movie (61- end)

**My Question**

How to concatenate/play two video urls between main url?

Any one help me out.. More than 16 hours headache with this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I got solution from official github issues

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3299

Solution is - **ClippingMediaSource**

**Sample implementation**

```
   MediaSource movieMediaSource = MyExoPlayer.getMediaSourceFromUrl(StreamPlayerActivity.this, mLiveURL);
    long oneMinute =  1000 * 1000 * 60 ;
    ClippingMediaSource videoSource1 = new ClippingMediaSource(movieMediaSource, 0,  oneMinute,false);
    ClippingMediaSource videoSource2 = new ClippingMediaSource(movieMediaSource,  oneMinute, 2 * oneMinute,false);
    ClippingMediaSource videoSource3 = new ClippingMediaSource(movieMediaSource, 2 * oneMinute, 10 * oneMinute,false);

    MediaSource adVideoSource1 = MyExoPlayer.getMediaSourceFromUrl(StreamPlayerActivity.this, mPromoVideoURL1);
    MediaSource adVideoSource2 = MyExoPlayer.getMediaSourceFromUrl(StreamPlayerActivity.this, mPromoVideoURL2);
    ConcatenatingMediaSource concatenatingMediaSource = new ConcatenatingMediaSource(videoSource1, adVideoSource1, videoSource2, adVideoSource2, videoSource3);
```

Comment: I am also trying the same but progress bar comes for individual media source and not for the entire concating media source. How did you resolve that?